# How to open a file for independent read/write?

Tags: c#, file-io

I'd like to open the same file for both reading and writing. The file pointer should be independent. So a read operation should not move the write position and vice versa.

Currently, I'm using this code:

```
FileStream fileWrite = File.Open (path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
FileStream fileRead = File.Open (path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
StreamWriter _Writer = new StreamWriter (fileWrite, new ASCIIEncoding ());
StreamReader _Reader = new StreamReader (fileRead, new ASCIIEncoding ());
```

But that leads to an IOException: *"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I just figured it out myself. In the second `File.Open`, we're trying to *deny* other applications write access by specifying `FileShare.Read`. Instead, we need to *allow* the first stream to write to the file:

```
FileStream fileRead = File.Open (path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

That's inherently correct, as the reading stream should not care about other people writing to the file. At least I don't get an exception anymore.

Comment: `FileShare` controls how access is shared with other `FileStream` objects (actually file handles), not with other threads or processes. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx:  "controlling the kind of access other FileStream objects can have to the same file.". The documentation at `File.Open` talks about threads. It's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a C# at hand, so I cannot test it.

Can't you just use FileAccess.ReadWrite instead of FileAccess.Read?

Edit: The answer is no. You need to use FileShare to do it.

Comment: I think that would not help much, since this would require even more rights on the file than the code in the OP did. Did you possibly mean *FileShare*? That's what worked for me, as seen in my answer.

Comment: In C/C++ I can open a file either in read, write or readwrite mode. In the last mode, I can read and write to the file. I'm sorry, I don't know much about C# and the required rights.

Comment: Ah, I think you misunderstood the question. You are right, FileAccess specifies whether we want to read/write/both. The important part, however, was the sharing mode. It turned out that the file has to be opened for reading with read-write-sharing after opening it for writing earlier.